# GetProperty("pname") returns null

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to get value for a dynamic property of a dynamic object.
Here is my Code..

```
public string ReturnProperty(object ob, string prop)
{            
    Type type = ob.GetType();
    PropertyInfo pr = type.GetProperty(prop);

    //Here pr is null..Dont know whats wrong

    return pr.GetValue(ob, null).ToString();
}
```

Comment: What values are `ob` and `prop`?

Comment: can you elaborate your code??

Comment: ob is dynamic object and prop is dynamic property. they generates dynamicaly from db. I need to have the value of dynob.dynprop

Comment: @incomplete: That's not really very descriptive. A short but complete example would make it much clearer.

Comment: if there are 10 businesses then bus.bname will give business name of a business, bus.bid will give business id and so on. So here property name i.e.(bname,bid,...) these are dynamic.

Comment: I hope `string prop` that you are passing as a parameter is a property and not a field. Just to confirm because this is a mistake some people make.

Comment: @incomplete, do you pass two strings to `ReturnProperty` function?

Comment: no it was a mistake by me there was no property name in the corresponding object for that ,so ovbiously its null. sorry. Ive got it now

Answer (score 41, accepted):

My guess is that either it isn't a public property, or you've got the name wrong, or it isn't a property at all (but a public field).

It's impossible to say more without knowing what the actual type is, but that should be a start.

You mention that this is a "dynamic object" but that's not really very descriptive. Bear in mind that the CLR itself doesn't know anything about the DLR - if you mean this is a type which implements `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider` or extends `DynamicObject`, then you won't be able to get at the properties with "normal" reflection like this.

Comment: I was having a similar problem and indeed  I didn't have a property at all, but a public field! Using FieldInfo instead of PropertyInfo worked for me.

Answer (score 11):

In my case `ob` did not have `pr` **getter setter** properly.

```
//causes GetProperty to return null
public class MyClass{
    public object pr;
}

//Works
public class MyClass{
    public object pr { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This means you did not have a property, but a field.

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I had to define get and set. See post above

```
public string MyPropertyName { get; set; }
```

After this I could get the property by:

```
typeof(MyClassItem).GetProperty("PropertyName")
```

Answer (score 6):

If the item you are attempting to access doesn't have getter and setter accessors, then most likely it is a field.

So your code would work as follows:

```
FieldInfo fieldInfo = type.GetField(fieldName);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the `Type.GetProperty(String, BindingFlags)` overload and select the right binding flags.

Answer (score 0):

Example for ExpandoObject(it implements IDynamicMetaObjectProvider Jon Skeet mentioned):

```
    public static string ReturnProperty(object ob, string prop)
    {
        if (ob is ExpandoObject)
        {
            return ((ExpandoObject)ob).Single(e => e.Key == prop).Value.ToString();
        }
        Type type = ob.GetType();
        PropertyInfo pr = type.GetProperty(prop);
        return pr.GetValue(ob, null).ToString();
    }

    //--

    dynamic dyna = new ExpandoObject();

    dyna.Name = "Element";

    Console.WriteLine(ReturnProperty(dyna, "Name"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, the problem lies in the field names, if you have a field to read from the sql "isField" and its class has a field is named "IsField". The compiler will read case sensitive , for all reason it's a different field, for that reason you have null. Check yours casesensitive fields nomenculature.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to access a public property, but I was using `BindingFlags.NonPublic` instead of `BindingFlags.Public`.

Answer (score 0):

Another consideration is whether your Property Name is correct when coming from a file.  For example when I read a CSV file as a byte[] my column headers are UTF-8 and have BOM characters for example: ZWNBSPMyProp vs. MyProp.  Put your MyProp name in notepad++ and show all characters.

Answer (score -1):

I tried this & it worked.

```
public string ReturnProperty(object ob, string prop)
{
    Type type = ob.GetType();
    PropertyInfo pr = type.GetProperty(prop);
    //Here pr is null..Dont know whats wrong
    return pr.GetValue(ob, null).ToString();
}

ReturnProperty(new { abc = 10 }, "abc");
```

Whats wrong???

Comment: how were you calling `ReturnProperty(new { abc = 10 }, "abc");` before?

Answer (score -1):

I just came across this issue when I was passing in the wrong data of a sorted grid view in an MVC project.

```
        public HolidaysGridViewModel()
    {
        this.Sort = "HolidayDate"; // this was the wrong name 
        this.SortDir = "ASC";
    }
```

It made me realize after reading your question that you were most likely passing in the name of a business from the database instead of the name of the database column object and therefore no were results were found which may have been the cause of your null value.